# Does changing root permissions matter?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, root, ubuntu-16.04

I see many times when dealing with password or other confidential files, tutorials and the like recommend changing the file permissions to 400. This seems odd because root, I have learned, is like the Alpha and Omega of Linux. So to make this a question conforming to the guidelines I want to ask like this:

## Does changing the permission of of file to 400 actually prevent root from writing or executing to that file? and if so, in what way?

like from a bash script or program  but not if I, as the user, manually do something to the file.

Comment: *"I see many times when dealing with password or other confidential files, tutorials and the like..."* -- You need to provide several examples for proper context.

Comment: I didn't provide examples because I didn't feel it added to the question, nor does it change my question. I just wanted to give some scope as to why I'm asking. However, since you asked I will provide examples as it may help in a way do not currently foresee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, without permission to write or execute a file, even for root, the normal syscalls to write or execute that file will fail and the app (or command-line tool or whatever) will have to do something different to handle the situation. In a well written app, the user will be notified of the error and given a chance to cancel the operation, or explicitly choose to override it.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question, it seems that making a file without write permission to root adds a prompt or user interaction in order to overcome the permissions, which is very useful.